# How to automatically move object after randomizing its position

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My goal here is to make the red boxes move downward in a straight line from whichever randomized position they are generated from. But what is happening so far is that each red box is moving down but not continuously like I want it to. I tried somehow using the enumerate function but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
import sys
import random
import time
import turtle
import pygame

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor ("black")
wn.setup (width=800, height=600)

droid_box = turtle.Turtle()
droid_box.speed (0)
droid_box.shape ("square")
droid_box.color ("red")
droid_box.shapesize (stretch_wid = 1, stretch_len = 1)
droid_box.penup()

droid_pos = [random.randint (-401, 401),300]
droid_list = [droid_pos]

def update_droid_position(droid_list):
    for z, droid_pos in enumerate(droid_list):
        if droid_pos[0] >= -400 and droid_pos[1] <= 300:
            droid_pos[1] += droid_box.dy


for i in range(-401, 401):
    droid_pos = [random.randint (-401, 401),300]
    droid_list = [droid_pos]
    droid_box.goto(droid_pos)
    droid_box.dx = 0
    droid_box.dy = -15
    droid_box.setx(droid_box.xcor()+ droid_box.dx)
    droid_box.sety(droid_box.ycor()+ droid_box.dy)
    droid_list.append([droid_box.xcor(), droid_box.ycor()])
    time.sleep(1)

while True:
    wn.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not dealing with *boxes* but rather a single box at a time.  Below is a rework of your code that creates and manipulates multiple boxes:

```
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

DX, DY = 25, 10
DROID_COUNT = 33
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600

def update_droid_positions(droid_list):
    moved_any = False

    for droid in droid_list:
        if droid.ycor() > CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT/2:
            droid.setposition(droid.xcor() + randint(-DX, DX), droid.ycor() - DY)
            moved_any = True

    return moved_any

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(False)

droid_list = []

def move():
    if len(droid_list) < DROID_COUNT:
        droid = Turtle()
        droid.hideturtle()
        droid.shape('square')
        droid.color('white', 'red')
        droid.penup()
        droid.setposition(randint(-WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2), HEIGHT/2)
        droid.showturtle()
        droid_list.append(droid)

    if update_droid_positions(droid_list):
        screen.ontimer(move, 100)

    screen.update()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

It's not exactly the same as what you were doing, just an example of smooth motion of multiple turtles.